# R - Covert a timestamp to epoch

Tags: r, timestamp

Have a look at the timestamp below.

```
2021-05-21T10:05:25:932Z
```

How do I convert the timestamp to epoch?

I took some time to look at similar questions and I have tried those suggestions but sadly without succes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `as.POSIXct` to convert the string to timestamp and use `as.numeric` on it to get the epoch time.

```
string <- '2021-05-21T10:05:25:932Z'
as.numeric(as.POSIXct(string, format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS', tz = 'UTC'))
#[1] 1621591525
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make this shorter

```
as.numeric(as.POSIXct(string, format = '%FT%T', tz = 'UTC'))
[1] 1621591525
```

#### data

```
string <- '2021-05-21T10:05:25:932Z'
```